# R row-wise sampling with upside down normal distribution

Tags: r, random, sampling

I have a data frame `DF` that looks like this:

```
Min Max
10  80
20  90
40  120
```

I want to append a new `Random` column with a randomly generated number between the min and max values per row. The sampling of the number shall be derived from an upside down normal distribution and exclude the middle values like illustrated below

[image]

The below prototype code with single variables seem to work but I'm stuck with how to apply this row-wise.

```
min <- 1
max <- 20
q <- min + (max-min)*rbeta(10000, 0.5, 0.5)
q <- q[!(q > 5 & q < 15)][1:10000]
hist(q)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this iterative approach. Use the variables `lower` and `upper` to define the excluded middle range.

Start by creating a column of `NA` values. For each iteration of the loop, all `NA` values in the column are overwritten with samples from your distribution. The samples that are within the excluded zone are then overwritten with `NA` and the loop repeats until no `NA` values are left in the column.

```r
DF    <- data.frame(Min = c(10, 20, 40), Max = c(80, 90, 120))
lower <- 5
upper <- 15

DF$sample <- rep(NA, nrow(DF)); 
while(any(is.na(DF$sample))) 
{ 
  i <- which(is.na(DF$sample)); 
  DF$sample[i] <- DF$Min[i] + (DF$Max[i] - DF$Min[i]) * rbeta(length(i), 0.5, 0.5); 
  DF$sample[DF$sample > lower & DF$sample < upper] <- NA;
}

DF
#>   Min Max   sample
#> 1  10  80 31.88867
#> 2  20  90 33.26248
#> 3  40 120 80.08321
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It worked smoothly. Despite the iterative nature it wasn't too demanding in terms of processing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
This calculates the 25% and the 75% cutoffs where the values may not lie between and samples so long until it may return a value. Also it is executed in a row-wise manner.

```
library(dplyr)
fun <- function(min, max){
  repeat {
  x <- min + (max-min)*rbeta(1,0.5,0.5)
  q1 <- min + (max-min)*pbeta(0.25,0.5,0.5)
  q2 <- min + (max-min)*pbeta(0.75,0.5,0.5)
  if(x<=q1 | x>=q2) break
  }
  return(x)
}

df <- data.frame(min=1:20, max=21:40)
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(value=fun(min, max))


> Source: local data frame [20 x 3]
> Groups: <by row>

> # A tibble: 20 x 3
>      min   max value
>    <int> <int> <dbl>
>  1     1    21  3.38
>  2     2    22  7.48
>  3     3    23  3.02
>  4     4    24  4.47
```